# AsyncTask doesn't finish after running doInBackground Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-camera

I'm running an AsyncTask on my `TakePic` class. In `doInBackground` function I'm using `Camera.takePicture` function. Now everything is fine at this point; I'm taking the picture and saving the file to /sdcard/%d.jpg that location.

```
public class TakePic extends AsyncTask<CameraPreview, String, Integer> {

  @Override
  protected Integer doInBackground(final CameraPreview... params) {
          params[0].camera.takePicture(null,null,new Camera.PictureCallback() {
              @Override
              public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                  FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                  try {
                      outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                      outStream.write(data);
                      outStream.close();
                      Log.e("picture_saved", "Picture has been saved succesfully: " + data.length);
                      camera.release();
                  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                      Log.e("file_not_found: ","couldn't save the file "+e.getMessage());
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                      Log.e("IOexception: ","couldn't save the file "+e.getMessage());
                  }
              }
          });
      Log.e("doinback_compt:" ,"done");
      return 0;
  }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
   }
}
```

But after I execute this AsyncTask on my main class it doesn't finish. I need to execute another function and I have to wait until this AsyncTask finishes. So after I execute the AsyncTask I'm using a while loop to check the status of the task but the status never changes.

```
    TakePic backCam=new TakePic();
    backCam.execute(cameraPreview_front);
    while (backCam.getStatus()!= AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
        *waiting for async task to finish*
    }
```

It stuck at the while loop and my logcat show that doInBackground running normal, and  the file is saving to that location.

```
10-10 18:06:14.497 15975-15975/com.urun.camera_test E/clicked_capture:: ok
10-10 18:06:14.633 15975-16452/com.urun.camera_test E/doinback_compt:: done
```

So what am I need to do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think that it doesn't finish?

Comment: It seems to me, that you have incorrect check in your while loop. And because of this, your  `*waiting for async task to finish*` is not working correctly

Comment: That's an incorrect way of using the `AsyncTask`, since your `while` loop effectively blocks the UI thread. Move the code that you want to execute after the `AsyncTask` completes into `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: I use debugging on the app and I put a breakpoint to the while and I checked that it goes to the loop like for 40 times(I stop at this point). It finishes running the doInBackground function but the status always return as 'RUNNING'.

Comment: @Egor What you're saying is true but it is not my priority right now i just need to wait so I use it like that for now and I need to start another AsyncTask after this one finish so I can't do it on onPostExecute().

Comment: Pass a listener to the constructor and wait for the response. Using a while loop kills the purpose of the AsyncTask. More explicit and focused too.

Comment: In this case there's no reason for using the `AsyncTask`, just run your code on the main thread. `AsyncTask` doesn't gain you anything when used in this fashion.

Comment: @Egor No I will be changing the structure of my code later, right now I need to run it like that to test that as soon as this async task completes the other async task runs.

Comment: `I have to wait until this AsyncTask finishes` .. the right way to go about this is to use observer/listener pattern. When the first task finishes have it trigger the listener, which can then start the next task. I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish but busy waiting in your UI thread like this is just wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is being handled in an odd way. First `CameraPreview.camera.takePicture()` will run in the background itself, that is why you pass it the `Camera.PictureCallback` in the constructor. You are simply stacking threads there. Try this in the main thread

```
[yourCameraPreview].camera.takePicture(null,null,new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        camera.release();
        // Read below
    }
}
```

Now we can just wait for the picture callback. Once we get data back, we can call an AsyncTask to store it in the file, and apply our own callback to wait for it's response. We can utilize a static inner class to make this all work.

```
private static class ImageSaver extends AsyncTask<Byte, Void, Exception>{

    public interface ImageSavedListener{
        void onImageSaved(Exception e);
    }

    private ImageSavedListener mCallback;

    public ImageSaver(ImageSavedListener callback){
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doInBackground(Byte... data){
        if(data == null || data.length == 0)
            return new Exception("Data returned from camera is invalid");

        try {
            FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
            outStream.write(data);
            outStream.close();
            Log.d("picture_saved", "Picture has been saved succesfully: " + data.length);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("file_not_found: ","couldn't save the file "+e.getMessage());
            return e;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IOexception: ","couldn't save the file "+e.getMessage());
            return e;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Exception e){
        if(mCallback != null)
            mCallback.onImageSaved(e);
    }
}
```

Then call it like this (in the section stated `Read below` above)

```
new ImageSaver(new ImageSavedListener(){
    @Override
    public void onImageSaved(Exception e){
        if(e == null){
            // do what you want
        }
        else
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}).execute(data);
```

This will take the picture in the background, wait for the response, save the response to a file in the background, wait for the response, and then do what you want based on the exception returned after saving.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do some code after `AsyncTask` execution, I can suggest one solution.
Wrap your `*waiting for async task to finish*` code in `Runnable` and send it as a param to Async task ( but this is not the best solution, just fast one )

```
    new AsyncTask<Object, Void, Runnable>() {
        @Override
        protected Runnable doInBackground(Object... runnables) {
            CameraPreview cp = (CameraPreview) runnables[0];
            Runnable callback = (Runnable) runnables[1];

            /**your main logic*/

            return callback;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Runnable aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            if (aVoid != null)
                aVoid.run();
        }
    }.execute( cameraPreview , new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /**code to run();**/
        }
    });
```

---

Possible problem with your current code is :

You are not executing  `super.onPostExecute(integer);`

Try change code to

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
 super.onPostExecute(integer);
}
```

Comment: Ok where am I going pass my own CameraPreview parameter?

Comment: @AhmetUrun as first param. Updated AsyncTask

Comment: Seriously? 1. read update  2. post your edited code. This is example. Not copy/paste variant

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out before, does not make sense blocking your main thread waiting do certain event. However, if you still want to get a something from your AsyncTask, I would advise you to use [FutureTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in your code, the AsyncTask is finishing correctly. 
The problem is that you are taking the picture inside the AsyncTask. So while the Camera.PictureCallback is waiting for the picture the task ends immediately after call the "takePicture" method.

What I should do is something like this (this is only an approach):

```
  public class TakePic {

    public interface MyTakePicListener{
        void onPictureTaken();
        void onPictureError();
    }

    private MyTakePicListener myListener; 


    public void takePicture(CameraPreview cameraPreview) {
        cameraPreview.camera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] data, final Camera camera) {

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                        try {
                            outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                            outStream.write(data);
                            outStream.close();
                            Log.e("picture_saved", "Picture has been saved succesfully: " + data.length);
                            camera.release();

                            HERE you should call a listener to continue with your success code
                            myListener.onPictureTaken();
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.e("file_not_found: ", "couldn't save the file " + e.getMessage());

                            HERE you should call a listener to continue with your error code
                            myListener.onPictureError();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.e("IOexception: ", "couldn't save the file " + e.getMessage());

                            HERE you should call a listener to continue with your error code
                            myListener.onPictureError();
                        }

                        Log.e("doinback_compt:", "done");



                    }
                }).start();
            }

        });
    }

}
```

Please, let me know if this could help you.